# Running python code from RobotFramework taking too long

Tags: python, robotframework

I am running .py file using Robotframework. py file has a logic to compare two csv files and generate 2 new csv files with details of difference. This py file works well(within seconds) and smoothly when executed using python IDE but it is taking too long time to get completed (I kept timeout of 10min).

I am using Process Library along with my py file to run these together.

Run Process runs the .py file and returns the result to RF console. But in this case, it is getting timed out. I am using RF 3.2.2

Comment: running on windows?

Comment: Yes, running on windows

Comment: to reproduce/debug, post some reproducible code along with some test data.

Comment: Typically if "Run Process" hangs, is that you are piping the output to be read but you have not read the output .. This is normal behaviour in Windows, most likely the root cause for your hanging keyword call ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It worked by adding a logic into a function and calling that function into RF. I am not using Process Library as compare to earlier.

Comment: This question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used py as a library to import the python function to do desired task. It just enabled me to use that as a keyword inside my robot file. This was executed quickly with the right output. I could then print that to console.